# How to dismass modal viewcontroller without navigationcontroller?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have two `UIViewControllers`. There is no embedded navigationcontroller. They are connected by a segue, which is a "Present Modally".

I have a button on scene2. When it is clicked, I call this code:

```
self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

I can see the code is hit but nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is that you are popping a view controller from a non existing navigation controller.

Basically when you say `self.navigationController?` that returns `nil` because there is no navigation controller. So the pop function doesn't get called.

What you have to do is call `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to dismiss your controller and not pop it to back action:

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {});
```

Comment: You have an useless semi-colon, that's not required in Swift and its usage is discouraged if not extrictly required.